# 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error when trying to alter an array's values

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

My program is an interactive calculator, where the user may enter something like 'add 2 5' and it runs the `add()` function, returning '5'.

The way my program works is that it uses `strtok()` to break the user's input into tokens: the first token determines what the program does (i.e. adds, divides, etc), and the next two are the values used in the function.

The problem I am having is with my while loop that tries to put the 2nd and 3rd tokens (the values) into an array of integers:

```
char input[MAX]; 
char *token;
int values[2];
int counter = 0;
        
fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
token = strtok(input, " ");

while (token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    values[counter] = atoi(token);
    counter++;
}
```

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

An example of how the program is supposed to interpret the information:

```
if (strcmp(token, "add") == 0) {
    answer = add(values[0], values[1]);
}
```

An example of the `add()` function:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us exact sample input?  My guess is the `values` index is running past the end of the array.

Comment: This is broken from inception, and not just because `counter` may exceed the dimension of `values` (which it may, as there is no control to prevent it). Look at that loop. What will break the iteration? When `token` is `NULL` (which we're assuming it won't be when first going in). Um.. you're loop guarantees invoking `atoi` with a `NULL` argument on the last iteration prior to breaking, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: You need to check the return values of all functions: fgets and strtok in this case.

Comment: This is only an extract of the code. We need a [mcve], because the error could arise on code that you have not shown.

Comment: I have only just noticed the questions, so thank you for inputting. I am gonna leave this problem for a little bit, as I don't quite have the time to go through it right now. I feel, though, that I need to understand more of the principles behind how C works, as it is something I am new to. It's so easy to get things wrong without even noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check if `token` is `NULL` **after** `token` is updated.
Also, you will want to save the pointer to the first token (command) to interpret it later.

```
char input[MAX]; 
char *token;
char *command; /* add this */
int values[2];
int counter = 0;
        
fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
token = strtok(input, " ");
command = token; /* add this */

while (token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (token == NULL) break; /* add this */
    values[counter] = atoi(token);
    counter++;
}
```

Then, use the saved pointer to interpret.

```
if (strcmp(command, "add") == 0) { /* use command, not token */
    answer = add(values[0], values[1]);
}
```